# payload format invalid error in push notification windows phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7, push-notification, mpns

I downloaded the sample program for push notification in the site http://chris.59north.com/post/Using-Windows-Phone-7-Push-Notifications.aspx

but i could not run this..

i am getting "payload format invalid error"

in some other post it asked to remove even contenttype and window-target header but still i am getting the same error :(

can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thanks for the viewers i solved this issue.. by pinning the shelltile.. and it works fine :)